# MS-Access users can not access linked text file

Tags: ms-access, text, record-locking

I have a small Access database that is distributed amongst several users.  They are not on my network, so we set them up with a small Access database that links to a txt file that we send them, so they have the ability to run canned queries/reports (that are just a copy of our main database's reports).

The problem is that if two users try to run reports (there is only one source table - the linked text file), then one of them gets locked out.  We checked the folders and everyone has read/write access to the folder (but again we're just reading the text file, so does it matter if they have write access?).

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Does Access automatically make a link to an external text file exclusive?

Comment: (1) Where do the users put the file and is it shared by more than one user? (2) Do multiple users share the same Access database? (3) Please define 'locked out'... does that mean two users can't get into Access, or they can't access the same file? (4) Just curious how Access is accessing the text file?

Comment: Users have copies of the access database on their local drives.  The external text file is on a shared network folder.  All copies of the database link to this single text file.  When a second user tries to run reports  while someone else is using their own mdb, then they get a file is locked error.  The txt file is linked.  It's not imported.

Comment: This is my first attempt at linking Access to a txt file.   I usually use MySQL or Access.  I've never seen this lock happen before.

Comment: Please explain exactly how the text file is accessed. Is it via VBA?

Comment: Access may indeed be locking since you mention that its linked to the file. instead of linking to it, i would recommend importing the txt file into an actual table, performance would be much better. to do that, copy down the txt file locally to their machine, import, and then run the queries. it should all be really 2-3 lines of code, and perhaps you want to make sure you truncate the table before each import attempt.

Comment: @wayne, the link is set up using MS-Access linked table manager.  The reports are run via a combination of VBA and SQL but that's not really relevant.  All the user does is open the database, select a report option on a pre-made form that runs queries/reports I've created for them.  It's all automated.   I don't want individual users to import because it's a daily txt file being transmitted and having multiple sources of data at their end causes data integrity issues.  A single text file, sent to one location, with an Access link to that location ensures that only that data is being used.

Comment: Don't do individual imports. Import the text file to a (new) Access database file which you hold in a shared folder on the network (a backend database). Then let users link to the table in that database. This setup will allow multi-user access - and will also be speedier when creating the reports.

Comment: Thanks Gustav and everyone.  It was pretty simple to set up, but don't having the extra MDB file kicking around, but it should work.  (Posting the code in Answers for anyone who might interested)

Answer (score 1):

I finally just created a linker.MDB that will sit on the same shared folder as the data.TXT file at the client's location.  (I don't have access to their network, and relying on my contact to place files where they need to go).

When the user opens their client.MDB file on their local PC, it will have a link to table on the linker.MDB, called "dailydata"

Also, their client.mdb will run code to open the linker.MDB database, run the following to import the txt file, and then close the linker.MDB database.   This ensures that the data in the linker.MDB is always up to date with the latest.   I may play around with the date attributes to only let the first call import the text file, but we'll see.

```
strPath = CurrentProject.Path

strFullName = strPath & "\data.txt"

strTable = "dailydata"

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strFullName, True
```